# Turn off disable free delivery on Google Product feed

Tags: google-product-feeds

We are using Magento 2,  We submitted the Google Product feed through Google Merchant.
However, All of the products have **shipping** prices.

We are getting customers calling us when they see the products on Google Shopping showing it's "`free delivery`".

They are confused and we keep telling them there's no free **delivery**.

Is there a way to turn off or disable the free **delivery** on Google Product feeds?